# weird NumberFormatException for my app downloader

Tags: android, exception

I had recently released an Android game in google play and I received a crash report of this **NumberFormatException**

I even pin pointed the code from which it is coming from.. But the thing which concerns me the most is the exception is not being thrown in any of the devices i have tested (and i have tested it in many devices)..

I have a string file arranged like this...
"10.48,1.6,90.0,1.155,1.73" where each float is separated by a comma... I don't know why this weird exception has occurred for the user of my app :(

Here is the code which i am using to parse from the file

```
 while(j<line.length())
        {
            if(line.charAt(j) == ',')
            {
                endingPoint = j;
                planetList[i].add(Float.valueOf(line.substring(startingPoint, endingPoint)));
                startingPoint = j+1;
            }
            else if(line.charAt(j) == 's')
            {
                i++;
                startingPoint = j+1;
            }
            j++;
        }
```

and here is the line which is throwing the exception...

```
cam = new Camera(Float.valueOf(df.format(worldWidth)),fourPointEightFixer);
```

HERE IS THE STACK TRACE THE KIND USER OF MY APP SENT:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
at  org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321) 
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323) 
at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:362) 
at com.OnMyOwn.Game.WackyGravity.<init>(WackyGravity.java:97) 
at com.OnMyOwn.Game.LevelChooserMod.initiateGame(LevelChooserMod.java:550) 
at com.OnMyOwn.Game.LevelChooserMod.onButtonTouchUp(LevelChooserMod.java:576) 
at com.OnMyOwn.Game.LevelChooserMod.update(LevelChooserMod.java:384) 
at com.OnMyOwn.framework.impl.GLGame.onDrawFrame(GLGame.java:165) 
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1363) 
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Comment: the string file represent the level data for the game...

Comment: Locale ... almost whole europe likes commas not dots as decimal separator ... and you didnt say how you parse it ...`NumberFormat.parse` or what ?

Comment: I parse it using my own code checking if comma exists and seperating the float numbers accordingly.. It works fine in all phones i hav tested!

Comment: jeez ... from what function/method you've getting `NumberFormatException` ... post full stack trace ... fx.: `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).parseDouble("44.44")` == `NumberFormatException`

Comment: BLOB,  can you provide the code you are using by editing your question?

Comment: i am not able to solve stack trace here.. character limit :( how to post it?

Comment: Selvin, can u post the fix again plz...

Comment: Change the separation symbol to another one, like a pipe `|`. Using comma as a separator for a number is just a stupid idea, because what about `1,000.00`? It would be treated as 2 numbers...

Comment: @BLOB don't post the complete logcat here, only the stack trace!

Comment: more likely problem is with saving those values....

Comment: HAHAHAH.. yes.. I was stupid by storing numbers seperated by commas.. but numbers like "1,000" are not present anywhere because i am using decimal format as ###.## ... so yeah.. 1,000 will be converted to 000 isnt?

Comment: stack trace <br/>
java.lang.NumberFormatException
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:362)

Comment: Serious BLOB, how about editing your question and add the stack trace there? And the complete stack, not only the first 4 lines...

Comment: what locale(language) are you using on test device/emulator ? just change it to polish/german/"not english eu language"/ and try your program again... and if program crash ... just force Locale in parsing/toString method that you use in retrive/save those numbers to fx Locale.US ... then you should get the same result language independent

Comment: @BLOB also we need `df` definition

Comment: yes! I was able to reproduce the problem when i changed it to german!! hahahahahahhaha.. funny android is funny... so german phones consider comma as dot eh? nice.. question solved!!! thanx all

Comment: Please, please please please STOP YELLING

Comment: sorry.. got excited! I should say.. u guys at stack overflow are severely helpful

Comment: `so german phones consider comma as dot eh` .... yes ... as i said in my first comment `almost **whole europe** likes commas not dots as decimal separator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by language so catch this exception in case of  "."  and replace this with comma ","  **if you are using pattern** like this "##.###"

Comment: I am using ###.## pattern.. so i need to replace all dots with commas and all commas with some other character to solve it for all locales?

Comment: stupid idea if you need parse string with dot just force locale ... exceptions cost too much ...

Comment: Selvin... I did not understand what u meant.. I am fairly new to java itself and I did not understand what u mean by "exceptions are costly". Forgiv my ignorance

Comment: Yes you have to replace this "##.###"  with  this "##,###" on exception. and do the same stuff again in catch block with the replaced string got it?

Comment: yes.. I will do that.. So the problem is purely based on the locale?

Comment: ... but resolving this problem using an exception is bad solution ... you should force locale ...

Answer (score 1):

if this line causing the problem:

```
cam = new Camera(Float.valueOf(df.format(worldWidth)),fourPointEightFixer);
```

you should replace it with(assuming `worldWidth` is float/double):

```
cam = new Camera(/*cast (float) if worldWidth is double*/worldWidth,fourPointEightFixer);
```

first: there is no need to change this value to string and parse it again, second:
i'm pretty sure that `df.format(double/float)` could return string representation of double/float with comma as decimal separator on device where Language/Locale is set to Locale using commas as separator (almost whole non english europe)

or you can force locale when you creating/getting instance `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
```

i think that quick fix provided by Ali(catching exception) is not good solution(as catching expected exceptions is bad programming practice)